# Implementation of Queue using Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, c++14, c++17

I have written this code and am confused about why is it showing segmentation fault. I think my dynamic memory allocation is causing problems for me here. Can anyone tell me what is causing the segmentation fault in here and how to improve the code.

Also, please tell me if I can create the object with the **ClassName obj();** and store it in the stack instead of the heap. Or would this implementation be needed in some problems

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

class Queue
{
public:
    int rear, front, size,capacity;
    int* arr;
     
    Queue(int c)
    {
        capacity=c;
        rear=c-1;
        front=0;
        int *arr= new int[c*sizeof(int)];
    }
};


int isEmpty(Queue* queue)
{
    return (queue->size==0);
}

int isFull(Queue* queue)
{
    return (queue->size==queue->capacity);
}


void enqueue(Queue* queue, int x)
{

    if(isFull(queue))
        return;
    queue->rear=(queue->rear+1)%queue->capacity;
    queue->arr[queue->rear]=x;
    queue->size+=1;
}

int dequeue (Queue* queue)
{
    
    if(isEmpty(queue))
        return 0;
     int x = queue->arr[queue->front];
    queue->front= (queue->front+1)%queue->capacity;
   
    queue->size-=1;
}

int front (Queue* queue)
{

    if(isEmpty(queue))
        return 0;
    return queue->arr[queue->front];
}

int rear (Queue* queue)
{
    if(isEmpty(queue))
    return INT_MIN;
    return queue->arr[queue->rear];
}

int main()
{
    Queue* queue=new Queue();

    enqueue(queue,10);
    enqueue(queue,20);
    enqueue(queue,30);
    enqueue(queue,40); 
  
    cout << "Front item is "
         << front(queue) << endl; 
    cout << "Rear item is "
         << rear(queue) << endl; 
}
```

Comment: [I got compilation error](https://wandbox.org/permlink/tCyWzTy5g3S6NYWn) instead of Segmentation Fault.

Comment: What is causing this can you tell me? I doubt my dynamic allocation of Queue I feel.

Comment: please don't confuse different versions of your code / please only one question per question. I suppose `Queue* queue=new Queue();` is something you added later and only without you got a segmentation fault. It is not possible to get a segfault with the posted code

Comment: By the way, why are you declareing the functions to deal with the queue as dependent functions instead of member functions of `Queue`?

Comment: The **Queue queue = new Queue();** was always there and I am getting seg fault with it. Just tried running again and it is showing the same thing.

Comment: @MikeCAT I was referring a tutorial with it and there was an implementation as such.

Comment: `int *arr= new int[c*sizeof(int)];` -- It looks like you're reading `C` material and trying to apply it to `C++`.  The `new[]` is not the same as `malloc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code have at least 3 problems:

Firstly,

```
Queue* queue=new Queue();
```

will lead to compilation error because no default constructor is defined and another constructor is defined in the class `Queue`.

To fix this, you should do one of:

- Change this line to match the defined constructor like `Queue* queue=new Queue(1024);`
- Add default constructor to the class `Queue`
- Add default value of the argument `c` for the constructor of the class `Queue` like `Queue(int c = 1024)`

Secondly, the function `dequeue` have an execution path in which the execution reach at end of funciton without executing any `return` statement.

It seems `return x;` should be added at end of the function.

Thirdly, the line

```
int *arr= new int[c*sizeof(int)];
```

is bad because:

- This stores the pointer to local variable that will vanish at end of this constructor instead of the member variable.
- You don't need to multiply `sizeof(int)` because what to specify is the number of elements to allocate, not number of bytes.

The line should be

```
arr= new int[c];
```